# Bootstrap 5 progress bar doesn't update using $(".progress-bar").width(100)

Tags: progress-bar

I am unable to update a Bootstrap progress bar using this:

```
$(".progress-bar").width(100);
```

But I can update it via the css:

```
$(".progress-bar").css("width", "100%");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jaimefuhr/zb0s6e2t/28/

I am just curious as to why the first method will not work since I assume it's a shortcut for the second method?

Comment: In the first method you're setting it to 100 pixels and not 100%.